# Default parameters of struct templates

Tags: c++, templates, struct, default, parameters

I have a template struct tree_parse_info declared as follows:

```
template <
    typename IteratorT,
    typename NodeFactoryT,
    typename T
>
struct tree_parse_info 
{
  // ...
};
```

The compiler allows the follows code:

```
tree_parse_info<> m_info;
```

Why does this code compile even though we do not have default template parameters for the template struct tree_parse_info ?

Comment: It doesn't compile. Post the real code.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept it :) (Accept by clicking the green arrow.) Additionally, you can just comment on my answer instead of post a new one.

Answer (score 5):

If the class has been forward declared previously, you won't need to restate the default parameters. For example:

```
// forward declare only
template <typename T = int, size_t N = 10>
struct array;

// actual definition
template <typename T , size_t N>
struct array
{};

int main(void)
{
    array<> a; // uses the defaults it saw in the forward-declaration
}
```

Look above your actual definition to see if you forward declared it.

By the way, if you give defaults at one place, and differing defaults at another, you'll get a compile error:

```
template <typename T = int, size_t N = 10>
struct array;

// error: redefinition of default parameter
template <typename T = double , size_t N = 2>
struct array
{};
```

Try giving the code you showed us defaults that can't possibly accidentally match, like:

```
struct stupid_special_tag_type_lolroflwat {};

template <
    typename IteratorT = stupid_special_tag_type_lolroflwat,
    typename NodeFactoryT = stupid_special_tag_type_lolroflwat,
    typename T = stupid_special_tag_type_lolroflwat
>
struct tree_parse_info 
{
  // ...
};
```

If you get redefinition errors, you know you've given it defaults in some other location.

Comment: His question says he has no default parameters.

Comment: @Neil: Perhaps there is one above his actual definition, in a forward-declaration. It's only a guess, admittedly.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile your code with g++, I get the following error:

> tp.cpp:10: error: wrong number of
>   template arguments (0, should be 3)

So you must be compiling something other than the code you are showing us.

Comment: Same goes for MSVC: C2976: 'tree_parse_info' : too few template arguments

Comment: Same for Intel: `too few arguments for class template "tree_parse_info"`